# How to solve dual integral equations with a linear kernel function?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, special-functions, duality-theorems, integral-equations

I would like to find the solution to the following dual integral equations
$$
\int_0^\infty (1+\alpha t) A(t) J_1 (\rho t) \, \mathrm{d} t = f(\rho) \quad \quad (0 \le \rho < d) \, , \\
 \int_0^\infty A(t) J_1 (\rho t) \, \mathrm{d} t = 0 \quad\quad (\rho>d) \, , 
$$
where $\alpha$, $d$ and $f(\rho)$ are known quantities and $A(t)$ is the unknown function.
The system with $\alpha=0$ has originally been considered by Titchmarsh (Theory of Fourier Integrals, Oxford, 1937) p. 337

I was wondering if someone here has already come across a similar system before. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

R

Comment: @JoseGarcia any thoughts with regard to my questions? Could Mellin transforms be of help here? Thanks

Comment: @Chappers Can one use Mellin transforms here? Thanks.